# Jenkins plugins to setup a job by dev team with customized template

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a large development team to maintain for CI. Every next small team has their own jenkins job requirements . I would like to build a customized template in backend which will facilitate the setting up the Job in a very easy manner for the development team so whoever wants to have any kind of job, without reaching to SCM team, they can do themselves without giving admin access to each one of thm.

I am trying to find out a possible plugins which might help me out in this could not get ...

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Rajesh Kumar,

I had a similar situation at my old job. We found the following pattern efficient:

- create the template job in Jenkins
- dummy out all values that need to be substituted
- name it "template-abcxyz"
- disable the job so nobody runs it by mistake
- in the job description, tell developers which fields need to be substiututed

Whenever developers need to create a new job, just create a copy of the template job and follow the instructions in the description to substitute in the appropriate values. The process is simple enough that you can designate one buildmeister from each team to grant permissions to create/config jobs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Can you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0):

The [template plugin](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/jenkins-enterprise/plugins/templates-plugin) allows you to create a job where teams fill in the details. It's not free though (part of Jenkins Enterprise.)

If you are ok with teams having complete control over their jobs, you could just give them access. They don't need admin access in order to create a job.